# Is it possible to assign task notification via mail if the user is not in active directory in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to assign task notification via mail if the user is not in active directory ?

Comment: Is the user forms authenticated, or anonymous?

Comment: I created a simple staff list in my home page .. I filled there email id ... I want to send them message when assigned to workflow is used !!

Comment: Yes, I understand your question. I'm wondering if the person you want to email is an external user without access to your site, or if they're not in AD but can connect to the site using forms authentication. If they're an external user, you can use the Send Email action, but they won't be able to update any task you send. If they have access to your site, then they will.

Comment: yes the user is an external user without the site access and not even in active directory and just an item in my "staff" list where I have filled its email id and other details !

Comment: Then you can send an email, but you cannot assign a task.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a task creates an item in the Task list. People without access to your site cannot access the task list, which means they can't access the task. You can only send them an email.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think that "task assignment" will NOT work with external users.

But you probably can do something with SharePoint Designer Workflow. (Custom code can do almost everything... and I wont be talking about custom WF or stuff)

Anyway, what is the point in assigning a task for someone who can't access your sharepoint to complete the task item?